# How to get props passed to this.children in react using React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Modal component that I want to reuse to display different content based on scenaiors when user clicks on a button.

Content components can be eg: `<A/>` `<B/>`  so on..

Here is a `Button` component.

```js
const InfoIcon: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = (props) => {
  const { title, children } = props
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
        <Icon title={title}/>
      {React.cloneElement(<>{children}</>, { isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage of this component:

```js
<InfoIcon title = "Click to see information about A">
  <GenericModal type = 'A'>
</InfoIcon>
```

This is how the `GenericModal` looks like.

```js
interface Props {
  type: 'A' | 'B'
  isModalVisible: boolean
  setIsModalVisible: (value: boolean) => void
}

const GenericModal = (props: Props) => {
  if (props.type === 'A') {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={props.isModalVisible}
        onClose={() => {
          props.setIsModalVisible(!props.isModalVisible)
        }}
      >
        <AContent />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
  if (props.type === 'B') {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={props.isModalVisible}
        onClose={() => {
          props.setIsModalVisible(!props.isModalVisible)
        }}
      >
        <BContent />
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

However when I try to render

```
<InfoIcon title = "Click to see information about A">
  <GenericModal type = 'A'>
</InfoIcon>
```

I get a ts error:
`TS2739: Type '{ type: "A"; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible`.
Is it not possible to pass the props from `InfoIcon` to `GenericModal`?
I thought it would be possible by using this:

```
      {React.cloneElement(<>{children}</>, { isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible })}
```

Since, `isModalVisible` and `setIsModalVisible` is being passed here.